# Importing CSS from node_modules into JS modules results in "undefined" class name in generated html

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, node-modules, parceljs

I'm using Parcel and I could successfully import CSS/SCSS files into my React modules:

```
import * as styles from './my-component.css';
....
<div className= {`${styles.glory}`}>A text</div> // Which will be generated as <div class = "_glory_c5yp0">A text</div>
```

What I'm not able to do is to do the same for a CSS file in a `node_modules` package, say `bootstrap`:

```
mport * as styles from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
....
<div className= {`${styles.row}`}>A text</div> // Which will be generated as <div class = "undefined">A text</div>
```

What's missing here?

---

My .postcssrc:

```
{
  "modules": true,
  "plugins": {
    "autoprefixer": {
      "grid": true,
    },
    "postcss-modules": {
      "camelCase": true
    }
  }
}
```

My .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-env",
    [
      "@emotion/babel-preset-css-prop",
      {
        "sourceMap": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "regenerator": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Nothing fancy in package.json. Installed packages are `parcel-plugin-typed-css-modules`, `autoprefixer`,
`@types/autoprefixe`, and
`postcss-modules`

Comment: Just a guess - try `'~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'`

Comment: @Dominic Tilde symbol works for importing to a _(S)CSS file_. It's not intended for a JS file. Anyways, I gave it a go and no luck!

Comment: Ah yes true missed it was in JS

Comment: did you find a solution to this @Hans ?

Comment: @rissk13 Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here: https://parceljs.org/css.html#usage-with-existing-css-libraries
and here: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/3879#issuecomment-567196742.

In short, I needed to have a `.postcssrc` file in the directory:

```
{
  "modules": true,
  "plugins": {
    "autoprefixer": {
      "grid": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The documentation does no longer exist.